Scene and config file management best practice (a library for scenes ?)
I have a scene with assets, cameras HDR world, a cycles rendering and rendering presets, and I would like to use it as kind of a template file.
This way I could use this scene in several files knowing that if I change the template, it will update all other other files using this scene. Just like the asset library but for scenes and renders.
Does this feature exist ? Is it relevant ? I am looking for best practices.
Thanks.
